# innerHTML returns one word only

Tags: onclick, innerhtml

```
<body>
<p style="color:green" id="green" onclick=getIT("green beans")>1.Soy beans </p>


</body>
<script>




 function getIT (OneWord){
      var theWord= document.getElementById("green");

    theWord.innerHTML=OneWord;   }




</script>
```

The above code dosent change. if I type one word only it changes, but if I type a string it dosnt not change. Can't figure out why.

Comment: Please make sure your format your code by indenting it by four spaces. You may want to fix it up as some of the indentation is off.

Answer (score 0):

Your html is invalid, you need to rewrite your onclick handler to use `"` before and after the function, then wrap your string in single quotes (`'`) - or the other way around:

```
onclick="getIT('green beans')"
```

See this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d2295z51/)

Comment: Thanks, I guess an addeventlistener method would be better, but I just wanted to try this way too.